# Expectation and variance of random series

Tags: measure-theory

> Consider the random series $1\pm\dfrac12\pm\dfrac14\pm\dfrac18\pm\ldots$ with the assignment of a plus or minus in the $n$th term being decided by the toss of a coin. Compute its expectation value and variance.

The expectation is  given by $$E=\int_{[0,1)}f d\mu$$ which I computed to be $1$ by bounding from above (and below) with "simple functions" which take the signs from the $n$th term onward to all be plus (or minus, respectively).

(The "$1$st" term of the sequence is $\dfrac12$.)

Now the variance is given by $$V=\int_{[0,1)}(f-1)^2d\mu$$ This time I can't use the same method. To get a lower bound, for any series whose sum up to $n$th term is positive, I want to take the remaining signs negative, and for any series whose sum up to $n$th term is negative, I want to take the remaining signs positive.

The problem is that it is very hard to compute the integral of the simple function. How can I solve that?

**EDIT**: I would like to compute this using the Lebesgue integral even though there may be other ways to do it, because I'm reading about the Lebesgue integral and this is given as an exercise.

Comment: For the expectation, you can use linearity to directly show that the expected value is 1.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Calvin. However, I'm reading about Lebesgue integral and this is given as an exercise, so I would like to calculate it using the integral.

Comment: There is no reason why you can't phrase the indicator variables in Lebesgue measure terms. I'd demonstrate how to do expected value.

Comment: That may be the case, but then it would be hard to show linearity of expectation and linearity of variance (for independent variables), wouldn't it?

Comment: It would be as hard as proving the linearity of variance using Lebesgue measure (which is something that you would have done already).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply indicator variables. Use the linearity of expectation.

$$E[1 \pm \frac{1}{2} + \ldots ] = E[1] + E[\pm \frac{1}{2} ] + \ldots = 1 + 0 + 0 + \ldots = 0. $$

**Hint:** Apply indicator variables. For independent variables, variance is linear since covariance is 0.

$$Var[1 \pm \frac{1}{2} + \ldots ] = Var[1] + Var[\pm \frac{1}{2} ] + \ldots = 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16} + \ldots = ?? $$

---

To evaluate it in terms of Lebesgue measure, to each binary sequence $0.a_1 a_2 a_3 \ldots$, we associate the function $F = 1 + b_1 \frac{1}{2} + b_2 \frac{1}{4} + \ldots$, where $b_i = \begin{cases} 1 & a_i = 1 \\ -1 & a_i = 0 \\ \end{cases}$.

Then, $F = 1 + f_1 + f_2 + \ldots$, where all of these functions are lebesgue integer able. Hence, we may split them up, and get that

$$ \int F\, dx = \int 1 \, dx + \int f_1 \, dx + \int f_2 \, dx + \ldots = 1 + 0 + 0 + \ldots = 1. $$

Note that this is merely the proof of the linearity of expectation applied to this particular case.

Comment: Can you really split up an integral of an infinite sum like that?

Comment: @PJ Why not? You can easily approximate it by finitely many terms, which is the justification used in Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @PJMiller Lebesgue theorem gives sufficient conditions for the integral of a series and the series of the integrals to exist and to coincide. They are met here because the series $\sum\limits_n1/2^n$ converges (more refined conditions exist but here this one does the job).

Comment: @Did Thanks, I guess my point is that I haven't read about those theorems yet, and I believe they shouldn't be necessary for this exercise. That's why I'm asking for more "basic" ways to do this, e.g. using the approach I originally posted.

Comment: @PJMiller Sure, you can also break it up into positive and negative parts, and then bound those easily above and below. The above merely motivates the steps to take, and gives an explanation of why it works. If you want to complete proof, then you would have to fill in the relevant details to justify the steps of the Lebesgue integration, till you are satisfied.

Comment: @CalvinLin Okay, I guess I'll mark your answer and correct, and create a question that's more specific to what I want. Sorry about my troubles, and thanks!